# Trying to better understand monero mining

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, php

I'm attempting to write a monero miner in PHP (I know PHP). I'm not after hashing speed I'm after understanding what is happening.

I have looked over the "CRYPTONOTE STANDARD 008" document that seems to explain what to do once I have the block data, what I'm not sure about is the input I am supposed to run the Keccak hash on.

First, the input is hashed using Keccak [KECCAK] with parameters b =
   1600 and c = 512.

Any code samples in PHP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so far this is what I have
`
<?PHP
 $currentblock = file_get_contents("http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_stats/");

$myarry = explode( ",",$currentblock);

$difficulty = $myarry[0];


$temp =  explode( ":",$myarry[1]);

$height =$temp[1];



$hashrate= $myarry[2];
$total_emission= $myarry[3];
$last_reward= $myarry[4];
$last_timestamp= $myarry[5];

echo $currentblock;


echo "<BR><BR>";
$currentblock2 = file_get_contents("http://moneroblocks.info/api/get_block_header/$height");
echo $currentblock2;

Answer (score -1):

Keccak is ***nearly*** SHA-3.

Taken from [CryptoNoter](https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter/blob/master/CryptoNight.md)

> SHA-3 is based on (a particular instanciation of) Keccak, but with a couple minor differences from the original Keccak. Cryptonote was made before SHA-3 standardization.
>   - user36303

Comment: SHA-3 is based on (a particular instanciation of) Keccak, but with a couple minor differences from the original Keccak. Cryptonote was made before SHA-3 standardization.

Comment: This answer is wrong. SHA-3 and Keccak-256 3.0 **do not produce the same outputs** as explained by its author: https://twitter.com/mjos_crypto/status/933456673443901440 .

Comment: I think/ hope I have the hashing side of it down unfortunatly I need to beable to getwork from a pool.

Comment: I think I found most of what I need to connect with PHP using Curl currently working on writing a simple getwork function then I can test the rest of what I have. thanks.